# “The rural women” or “the women of a rural village/area”?

Tags: word-choice, expression-choice

Which one is more appropriate?

> Among the rural women of a village in X district
>   Among the women of a rural village in X district
>   Among the women of a rural area in X district

Comment: *rural women* is an odd way to phrase it.  The others are fine.

Comment: Rural women sounds rather strange, although I cannot for the life of me say why.  It should be a reasonable descriptor, but it isn't.

Comment: This is more like a logic question...if the women are of the village and the village is rural, then you can say "among the women of a rural village".  If you say "among the rural women of a village...", it sounds like there may be "rural" women and "not rural" or "urban" women in the same village.

Comment: But I see nothing wrong with saying simply 'Among the rural women of the northern Punjab'. Since rural life inevitably involves village-dwelling, the use of 'village' would seem superfluous. It is more complex in Europe. What were in earlier centuries 'villages' in a traditional sense, will nowadays contain up-market residences for two-car families where the adults earn their livings, shop and attend the gym in a nearby large town or city. Many villages will also contain people who earn their living in agriculture, or local trades. Villages can be a mixed bag.

Comment: @WS2, rural life does not always involve village-dwelling.  I live in a rural area and not in a village or town so technically I am a rural woman but not "of a village", hence my point about specifying if the women and/or the village is rural is important for disambiguation.

Comment: @KristinaLopez I doubt you are a 'rural woman' in the sense that this OP seems to be speaking. I presume you do not have to walk six miles each day to fetch water, in the way that some 'rural women' of India do. You may live in a rural area and even earn your living in agriculture but, what I was getting at when talking about Europe is that we no longer have people that are 'rural' in the sense that many were 150 years ago and billions in the third world are today. Country living in the rich world  is significantly gentrified, and nowadays has most, if not all the comforts of city dwelling.

Answer (score 1):

*[Rural](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/Rural)*, as an adjective, can apply to a person or a place.

> 1. (adj) of, pertaining to, or characteristic of the country, country life, or country people; rustic: rural tranquillity.
> 2. (adj) living in the country: the rural population.
> 3. (adj) of or pertaining to agriculture: rural economy.
> 4. (noun) a person who lives in a rural area.

If it's readily understandable that all women of the rural village are themselves rural, and it's a fact that the women, themselves, are rural, then any of your suggestions are fine.

If you are trying to make a point that the women are rural (rather than that they are women who happen to be of or from a rural village), then *rural women* is the right way to make that point.